# How to import "gson" in Fragment

Tags: android, gson, fragment

I don't get an "gson" error in the activity class, but I get an error when the trailer is written. How can I solve this error?

```
public class BarcodeReaderFragment extends Fragment {

@Override
public void receiveDetections(Detector.Detections < Barcode > detections) {
    final SparseArray < Barcode > qrcode = detections.getDetectedItems();
    if (qrcode.size() != 0) {
        Vibrator vibrator = (Vibrator) getActivity().getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
        vibrator.vibrate(100);
        Intent my = new Intent(getActivity(), ResultActivity.class);
        my.putExtra("type", qrcode.valueAt(0));
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        String json = gson.toJson(qrcode.valueAt(0));
        SharedPreferences sp = getActivity().getSharedPreferences("list", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        addhistory(sp, json);
        startActivity(my);
        getActivity().finish();
        barcodeDetector.release();
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Can you please post that error?

Answer (score 1):

You need to include the Gson library in your project as described [here](https://github.com/google/gson) and them import the `Gson` class like this: `import com.google.gson.Gson` (place this directly under the `package` declaration).

Comment: I added "Gson" to the library.  I've tried this before.  It is imported from the library in the activity class, but not in the track.

Comment: import com.google.gson.Gson   I wrote it by hand.  That didn't work, too.

Comment: If you hover on the red text, the IDE will show you an error message. What does it say?

Comment: Thank you for your interest. I added "gson" back to the library, the problem has improved.

Answer (score 0):

Please import library using gradle in your app gradle

```
implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.5'
```

[image]

Comment: I added "Gson" to the library.  I've tried this before.  It is imported from the library in the activity class, but not in the track.